# how to log all request in tastypie django

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have used tastypie in django to handle REST api request. When ever I do GET/POST request it comes to dehydrate method by default. But for DELETE/PUT request it doesn't have any method tastypie handles it, so there is no way to log request information.

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete']
    resource_name = 'project'
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    validation = FormValidation(form_class=ProjectForm)
    always_return_data = True
    filtering = {
        'id': ALL,
        'slug': ALL,
        }

def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()   #--> get/post request hit this function
    logger.log('app.main','debug', 'Project info', bundle)
    bundle.data['name'] = cgi.escape(bundle.obj.name)
    return bundle
```

Is there any function to override ModelResource in tastypie.resource module? so that for all request i get the bundle data first and then i will pass that to logger before it is processed.

Comment: Can't you log it on the WSGI middleware level, when the request is not yet routed? Or on the [Django middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/) level? If all you need is the request, and you have an idea how API URLs look like (e.g. `.startswith('/api/')`), it might suffice.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but if you can describe what the purpose is, it might be easier to point you in the right direction.

You say you would like to log request information, but logging the bundle in the `dehydrate` method doesn't do that, as any changes such as adding the primary key on a `POST` request are already done.

You might be better off logging the `request.body` directly in the `dispatch` method.

If you actually would like to log the response you can also do that in the `dispatch` method.

```
def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
  logger.info('Project info [request method]: %s' % request.method)
  logger.info('Project info [request]: %s' % request.body)
  response = super(ClassName, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)
  logger.info('Project info [response status]: %d' % response.status_code)
  logger.info('Project info [response]: %s' % response.content)
  return response
```